# Problem retrieving images from Canon vc-v50i camera

Tags: gscam, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm using ROS electric and trying to retrieve images from canon vc-c50i camera using gscam and image_view, but when i ran image_view the window was gray and there is no image, despite of there is no error messages when i ran these packages.

I'm

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12133/problem-retrieving-images-from-canon-vc-v50i-camera/) by [M](https://answers.ros.org/users/1457/m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suppose this may be kind of outdated but the brand of the camera catched my attention as we had a similar model except it used RJ45 and web access. Your model seem to provide a direct video signal (no usb/ no ethernet).

I just wonder how gstreamer (used un gscam node) gets the video signal out of your camera, are you using a video acquisition card ? Maybe the problem comes from the video card driver ? Can you get vlc to display the image (also uses v4l and /dev/video etc...)

---

Originally posted by [GuiHome](https://answers.ros.org/users/768/guihome/) with karma: 242 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0